# FTP users and folders management GUI

Tags: gui, ftp

At work we have FTP server for sharing big files (up to 2GB) with remote contractors. As remote contractors and projects are changing on weekly/monthly basis, I have a regular chore of managing FTP server.

Is there any GUI tool, web based or desktop program, that could help users with less technical experience (e.g. project managers) to manage FTP server?
It must have following functionality:

- folder management: create/delete folders in FTP server;
- user management: create/delete users, manage user access permissions (allow user to access specific folder with read-only rights);

Currently using vsftpd on CentOS 7 server. Clients are using Windows PCs and Macs. Migrating to other software solution is not a huge issue. Currently I have no budget - I need to make proposal to stakeholders first.

Comment: As this might very much depend on the server software used, could you please [edit] your post and include which one you're using? And while on it: please also add what OS it must run on, and what your budget is. Thanks!

Comment: @Joshas I know of WinSCP which is pretty nice for managing FTP/SFTP etc. But user management is usually not done over software like these. Initially, you could use Putty to connect to a server and then CRUD users.